# Не удается вызвать setState для компонента, который еще не установлен

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть 2 компонента: форма входа, форма регистрации. Есть функция, которая в зависимости от состояния отображает нужный компонент. Каждый компонент содержит в себе форму с кнопками, нажатие на кнопку меняет состояние с помощью метода setState(). При попытке изменить состояние появляется предупреждение:

> Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted.
>   This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application.
>   Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};`
>   class property with the desired state in the SignUP component.

Просмотрев документацию и примеры я не вижу ошибки в коде, может она в логике?
Больше кода тут: https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/158253/

Comment: почему не используете `jsx`? добавьте ваш код в вопрос, ссылка может устареть

Comment: что-то вы как-то вообще `React` не правильно готовите

Comment: @ThisMan, почему неправильно? Подскажите, совсем новичок

Comment: Вы выполняете render у не примонтированного в DOM элемента. Отсюда и предупреждение

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, что это значит? Почему элемент не примонтирован в DOM, потому что находится в другом файле?

Comment: потому, что у вас f = b.render() вместо ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(B, {}), document.getElementById("idForBComponent")); т.е. render происходит ДО монтирования

Comment: вам нужно перечитать документацию `React`a, вы в корне неправильно его используете

Comment: @ThisMan, неправильно, потому что возвращаю не верстку, а реакт элемент?

Comment: наоборот, вы зачем то вызываете `render` руками, так делать нельзя, `react` сам это делает

Comment: @DmitryKozlov оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach не вижу смысла. Код по ссылке уже изменен и не содержит обсуждаемых конструкций. Проголосовал за закрытие